# Insert Comment Reply Form Into Page Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, multithreading, forms, comments

I have been making a threaded comment system as a way to learn php and javascript/jquery properly. Ive done bits and bobs in the past but ive made a new years resolution to learn it properly.

Im having trouble inserting a reply form into the comment tree below the comment being replied to. I know this is probably pretty basic but how do you insert html into a page when someone clicks a link.

This code wasn't working for me:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        $('a#reply').click(function() {

            $(this).append("the html blah");    

        });
    });

});
```

Anyone see where im going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If none of the other suggestions are working, it could be your selector for the link is not working properly.  In the example you provided you appear to be looking for a link like this:

```
<a id='reply' href='#'>add comment</a>
```

Is that correct?  You didn't mention how you were generating the html, but I know with asp.net the server side id != the client side id and you would need to modify your selector like so:

```
$('a[id$=reply]')
```

In any case, here is a full example with html thats working fine for me:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='scripts\jquery-1.2.6.min.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style='height:400px'>
            Space to demonstrate that clicking the link does not scroll the page.
        </div>
        <div id='main'>
            <a href='#' id='clicky'>here</a>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('a#clicky').click(function(){
                $(this).after('Hello There')
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, i tried your code and its working now, think it might have been too many of $(document).ready(function(){ but whatever it was you've been a great help. Thank you.

Comment: Hi again Corey, i would be very grateful if you would help me again. I've found the function will only insert html for the first instance of of the a#id on the page. As every comment has a reply button this is a big problem, any ideas?

Comment: It's not valid html to have multiple element's with the same ID.  I would recommend changing that ID to a class, and then modify your selector accordingly $('a.className')

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('a#reply').click(function() {
            $(this).after("the html blah");
            return false;
        });
});
```

You may need the 'return false;' in there to stop the page from reloading itself when you click on the link.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to make sense but im still getting redirected to the top of my page. My link is just <a href="#">.

Comment: Linking to '#' will jump to the top of the page because it is looking for an anchor that will match it - in this case the first element (body) because it's a blank anchor. `return false` should circumvent that though. It can help to post a link to a test page or to paste the HTML above aswell.

Comment: Thanks for the help sancho but Corey found the problem in his post further down the page

Comment: this produces "the html blah" for every click for one comment when you click reply. 

Example:"the html blahthe html blahthe html blahthe html blahthe html blahthe html blahthe html blah". for each click, this addinf to comment, but i want to open a textarea and so it must be clickable only once. So is there any advices?

Answer (score 1):

To add to rodbv's answer you'll be adding the text "the html blah blah" **inside** the link that was clicked because you are using `append`. Change it to:

```
$(this).after("the html");
```

And it will write out the html **after** the link instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, still nothing comes up on the page. I am redirected to the top of the page as my anchor links to # (<a href="#">)

Comment: Add a "return false;" at the end of your event.